# ng add @angular/fire returns invalid project id: f_test

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

```
Angular CLI: 17.3.1
Node: 18.17.1
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.3.1

@angular/fire                   17.0.1
@schematics/angular             17.3.1
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.3
zone.js                         0.14.4
```

New project. When i try to add `ng add @angular/fire` it allows me to choose the features i would like to setup. When i select `Firestore` it asks me an account but when i select my account it returns "Invalid project id: name of my Angular project directory

I just want to add `ng add @angular/fire`

Comment: I tried replicating the issue, but I wasn't able to. After choosing the Firebase products that you want to use, the CLI will ask you to select between existing logged in account or login new account. Then, it will list all the projects inside that account. Would you mind sharing screenshot or steps you did before you encounter the issue? Did you manually enter the project id? Have you verified that the account has access to the given project?

Answer (score 0):

You can run these commands : `firebase projects:list` to list your projects and `firebase use` to switch between projects (as described in [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/)).